# Google App Engine StandardでJavaアプリが起動できません。

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Google App Engine Standardを利用してWEBアプリを開発しているのですが、特定の状況下で起動しようとすると、エラーが発生してしまい、起動ができません。
どなたか同じ事象になった方は知見を頂けないでしょうか？

##### 開発環境

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components) Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Java 8

##### プラグイン

Google Cloud Tools For Eclipse 1.8.4
Eclipse Tools for Cloud Foundry 1.2.0

Google Cloud SDK
Google Cloud SDK 450.0.0
app-engine-java 2.0.20
app-engine-python 1.9.106
bq 2.0.98
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.3.1
core 2023.10.06
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.26

#### 事象

- Google App Engine Standard Java Projectで新規プロジェクトを作成
- appengine-web.xmlの記述を以下の通り変更

  変更前:
  `<sessions-enabled>false</sessions-enabled>`

  変更後:
  `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>`
- App Engineで起動すると以下のエラーが発生して起動に失敗

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/apphosting/runtime/SessionStore
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:117)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SessionManagerHandler.create(SessionManagerHandler.java:75)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:360)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:293)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:42)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:102)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:118)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:280)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:57)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:229)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:227)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:227)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:381)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:58)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:239)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:230)
```

※sessions-enabledをfalseにして起動すると、起動に成功します。

Comment: [こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77280512/4506703)と同じ事象ではないでしょうか。最新(450.0.0)バージョンでのバグとあり、バージョンを下げる(449.0.0)と良さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
バージョンを下げたら無事に動きました。